# constant rotating device- how to receive valid orientation data?

Tags: android, rotation, sensors

I am currently implementing an speedometer by receiving orientation data from my phone. I am using

```
SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, gravity, geomagnetic);
float orientation[] = new float[3];
SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
float azimuth = orientation[0];
double azimuthD = Math.toDegrees(azimuth);
if(azimuthD < 0) azimuthD = 360 + azimuthD;
```

With this i am able to receive the rotation data from my phone, such as azimuth etc..
Anyway, this works fine while the device is placed on a table or something. But when rotating around a certain point (in my case the device is fixed on a wheel and rotating at a certain speed) the values are far away from being accurate. I believe, since I am using gravity and the geomagnetic sensor, there could be an conflict with forces that influence these sensors, while rotating. [As the wheel turns, the rotation changes relative to a point, but the local device rotation stays the same.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jOaA.png)

How can I access the orientation of the device while it's turning without running into a lot of noisy data?
I read some about the ´Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR´ property, but couldn't quite figure out how it works. Also I read about the possibility to remap the coordination system, but how is that supposed to help, since my phone is never not vertical to the floor more like with an angle of 5°-10°.
I would appreciate any help.

Cheers,
viehlieb

Answer (score 0):

I guess i found my answer.
The solution was to throw away all the code i posted above and use the gyroscope, obviously.
The gyroscope values measure angular velocity of the device's rotation. The coordinate system used is the devices own coordinate system. In my case the relevant value was the rotation around the z-axis.
Values are in radiant per second, which can be mapped to m/s if you figure multiply the wheel's circumference. So the trick was in the OnSensorChanged method:

```
if(sensorEvent.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE){
gyroscope = sensorEvent.values;
double rotZ = gyroscope[2];
double degrees = Math.toDegrees(gyroscope[2]);
//calculate the speed with circumference = 2.23m
float speed = (float) degrees/ 360.0f * 2.23f * 3.6f;
}
```

If now you'd like to have accurate values, you could store them in an array and calculate the average. Remember to clear the array every 20th time (or so) the onSensorChanged method is called. With SENSOR_DELAY_GAME registered there's sufficient data over which you could build the average.